# How to use a test bucket for MinIO?

Tags: python, django, object-storage

I'm writing a Django app, and I use Minio as my object storage. I use this python package.[enter link description here](https://pypi.org/project/django-minio-backend/)
I want to create a test bucket for my unit tests. What should I do?
In my models.py file, I add a default bucket to save objects; I don't know what I should do for the test request.
It is my model:

```
    class PrivateAttachment(models.Model):   
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="Object Upload",
                            storage=MinioBackend(bucket_name='django-backend-dev-private'),
                            upload_to=iso_date_prefix)
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist using a `backend-layer` like `django-minio-backend`, you should find a way adding a test bucket with that layer, documents say you can have multiple buckets by adding the buckets name to `MINIO_PRIVATE_BUCKETS` array in `settings.py`, give it a shot, add a test bucket name there, run your app and the bucket should be created, so you can refer to your test bucket.

```
MINIO_PRIVATE_BUCKETS = [
    'django-backend-dev-private',
    'my-test-bucket',
]
```

```
class PrivateAttachment(models.Model):   
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name="Object Upload",
                            storage=MinioBackend(bucket_name='my-test-bucket'),
                            upload_to=iso_date_prefix)
```

Comment: You know, I want to store general request to the  "django-backend-dev-private" bucket and test request file to "test-bucket", If I change the bucket name in model all the requests will go to the this bucket :( .

Comment: there's something I don't quite get here, and that's if your writing unit-tests why don't you mock minio? we usually mock blackbox functionalities in unit-testing.
second of all, you should have your test environment isolated, isn't it so? 
if I'm happen to be mistaken please provide us with more of your code.

Comment: Actually, for CI/CD in GitHub, I need to write tests and my MiniO server is running on my main project server instead of the GitHub server for ci/cd, So when I run tests in GitHub I need to use a different bucket to prevent unusable data in the main bucket.